# zerombr and clearpart not working in RHEL7

Tags: rhel, partition, kickstart, installer-anaconda

I've been using the following simple partitioning scheme to setup some RedHat machines.

```
zerombr
clearpart --all --initlabel
bootloader --location=mbr
autopart
```

The unfortunate part is that I know that as of RHEL 6.3 --initlabel no longer initializes new drives and has been swapped out for the `zerombr` option.
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/117513

I have both of these options included (to support legacy). But it doesn't seem like zerombr actually initializes the disks at all and when I check in the parted utility there is no disk label there and one needs to be created manually.

As you can see even with the `zerombr` and `clearpart --all --initlabel` I still have partition data on my disk during kickstart

```
(parted) print
Model: HITACHI HUS156060VLS600 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 600GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  839MB  839MB  primary               boot
 2      839MB   600GB  599GB  primary
 3      600GB   600GB  609MB  primary  fat32

(parted) mklabel msdos
```

And it then proceeds to error out and fails to continue installation until I reboot after running a mklabel.

Anyone have any ideas? Or is this possibly a bug that should be submitted to RedHat?

Comment: Not sure of the solution but when I encountered a similar problem here the problem turned out to be an error in the kickstart file.  This was silent in the graphical installer but when I switched to the text mode installer the error was reported shortly before the installer stopped allowing me to find and fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Workaround:

```
%pre  
vgchange -a n  
%end
```

Comment: Is `vgchange` available in your initrd in %pre? Not in mine for RHEL7 or RHEL8. I was hoping someone had used `partx` which I see is in fact available.